# Formating (matrix?) in reporting services 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to format a report in RS2005.

Notice the columns:
[image]

As you can see the columns are not the same for every pass. How do i format my report in this manor?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure consistent formatting on that table, you'll want to set the alignment for all the cells. The two properties to set are `TextAlign` for horizontal and `VerticalAlign` for vertical position.

Also, in that 4th column it looks like "Price" either has a return after it or is in a different row than the other headers. That's why it's not repeating like the others.